# SUM character in MYSQL

Tags: char, sum

Is it possible to use `SUM(FIND_IN_SET("f",ftype)).`

Note: type is a varchar type in MYSQL table column.And the possible value are **'f', 'v', 'g'.**

I want to count the total value of f in a column.

Comment: if the data in two records is `fan` and `uff`, are you expecting 2 or 3 as an answer?

Comment: @redcoder : It is possible. See my answer for demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL:

```
select sum(FIND_IN_SET('f',ftype) > 0) as total
from your_table
```

For MSSQL:

```
select SUM(
           case when CHARINDEX('f', ftype) > 0 
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end
           ) 
       AS total
from your_table
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c9e6/8).